# bootstrap fixed menu broke on scroll

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bootstrap landing website, and there are one problem. When menu scrolled to bottom of page, it's just lost (mobile phone!). I don't know how. Other screen's like monitor work ok. But on mobile I have this problem.

[Example](http://upersonalcoach.ru/)

I have tried to load menu after website loading

```
$(window).load(function() {
    document.getElementById("hideAll").style.display = "block";
});
```

Styling like:

```
.navbar{
    height: 80px !important;
    max-height: 80px;
}
```

Nothing help me, menu still lost on scroll to bottom of page (on mobile phone)

Comment: what you exactly want ?

Comment: just to fix lost mobile menu lost on scroll to bottom page. It is first time I see bug like this, and i don't know how to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check for the browser compatibility in mobile.Add `@mediascreen` in css file for that specific div class.